# does lucene standardanalyzer remove stopwords and have stemming function?

Tags: java, search, lucene

i have tested standardanalyzer with indexWriter and found that it automatically removes stopwords, however, i did not add stopwords list as following code is what i used

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35); 
        IndexWriterConfig config =new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, analyzer);
```

where is default stopwords list?
also, does this analyzer automatically stem words too??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [API docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_3_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html), there exists a default set of stopwords (taken from English language), stored in `StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET`. It is used if you create the analyzer with the constructor `public StandardAnalyzer(Version matchVersion)`, which is exactly what you do. The set is exactly the same as [`StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/2.4.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopAnalyzer.java#StopAnalyzer.0ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS). You can use one of the other constructors to pass the analyzer another (possibly empty) set of stopwords.

`StandardAnalyzer` doesn't stem words. If you need stemming, use for example `SnowballAnalyzer`.