# Lucene - default search lemmatization/stemming

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine, stemming, lemmatization

Does `Lucene` default search do lemmatization/stemming on the words?

For example when using the code in this [sample](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html), are the words in the docs used as is or are they transformed to their basic form (i.e. Managing -> manag), and if so what default lemmatizer does it use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [does lucene standardanalyzer remove stopwords and have stemming function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755071/does-lucene-standardanalyzer-remove-stopwords-and-have-stemming-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample referred in your post uses Lucene [StandardAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) which does not do stemming.

If you want to use stemming, you need to use an other Analyzer implementation e.g.: [SnowballAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html)